# How to change header names and note generated by stargazer?

Tags: r

How do I customize the header names "panel linear", "coefficient test"? In the package Stargzer?

I'm open to using another package as well to present panel model summary data results.

```
  library(stargazer)
  stargazer(random2, Rmodel3, 
      type='latex',header = FALSE,
      column.labels = c("RE", "RSE"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution using `stargazer` for me is to set `model.names = FALSE`, and then adding, as you have done, `column.labels`.

```
# library;
library(stargazer)

# run some random models;
model_1 <- lm(
        mpg ~ am, data = mtcars
)

model_2 <- glm(
        mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars
)



# Print stargazer output; 
stargazer(
        model_1, model_2,
        column.labels = c("\\textit{OLS}", "\\textit{MLE}"),
        model.names = FALSE,
        type = "text" # Remember to change this to 'latex'.
)
```

Which gives the following `output`

```
====================================================
                          Dependent variable:       
                    --------------------------------
                                  mpg               
                             OLS              MLE   
                             (1)              (2)   
----------------------------------------------------
am                         7.245***                 
                           (1.764)                  
                                                    
cyl                                        -2.876***
                                            (0.322) 
                                                    
Constant                  17.147***        37.885***
                           (1.125)          (2.074) 
                                                    
----------------------------------------------------
Observations                  32              32    
R2                          0.360                   
Adjusted R2                 0.338                   
Log Likelihood                              -82.653 
Akaike Inf. Crit.                           169.306 
Residual Std. Error    4.902 (df = 30)              
F Statistic         16.860*** (df = 1; 30)          
====================================================
Note:                    *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

I'm a huge fan of `stargazer`, but it is, from time to time, tedious to work with.